# How to quickly do a clay render?

Tags: rendering, materials

Sometimes, I find that it is useful to do a Clay Render for my model, where all of the materials render with a single common "clay"-like material (see example image below). In the past, I have done this by:

- Selecting all of my objects by using the <kbd>A</kbd> hotkey
- Manually deselecting the World object, camera, and lights in the Outliner
- Linking materials using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
- Manually setting to the same material in the Properties>Materials menu
- Render like normal

When I was done with my Clay render, I would revert to the old version by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> a few time. However, this is a rather clunky solution, since I can't make any edits in the clay version without losing my old materials/textures data.

Is there a better way to do Clay renders, either with an addon or through some other technique such that I can make edits to my model and not lose my materials? If at all possible, I would like a single setting that allows me to quickly toggle clay-mode on and off in the same file.

**Example "Clay Render":**
[image]

Comment: I think clay render is also available for cycles, it's already included in recent blender version and it's easier to use than the wireframe addon. BTW Gwenn did you answer your own question?

Comment: @micgdev It's perfectly fine to [ask and answer your own question(s)](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In the **Properties** area, **Render** tab, **Layer** group, there's a setting to override every object's material:

[image: Material Override]

As of **Blender 2.8x** there is a new *Override* panel as part of the [View Layer Properties](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/layers/layers.html#override):

[image]

Comment: Note that this only works in Blender Internal. In Cycles, there is no 'Light' option, and the 'Material' option ends up overwriting Emission shaders.

Comment: @Gwenn, unless your using regular lamps instead of emission shaders. I use this method even in cycles.

Comment: @Gwenn It also does not override environment lighting (coming from HDRI enviroment map for example).

Comment: You can use an "Ambient Occlusion" shader fot the clay material in Cycles. Mesh based lights might get lost, but since "Ambient Occlusion" does not use lighting, you still will get a nice geometry preview.

Answer (score 10):

The short answer is that it depends on which render engine you are using.

**Cycles: Wireframe addon**

The ['Wireframe'](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?239505-setup-a-wire-render) addon will allow you to toggle clay materials on your objects using the 'Object Tools' panel.

To use the addon:

- Download the addon from [this site](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16486113/Blender/archivos/wire_mat_gui.py)
- In your User Preferences>Addons view, choose 'Install from File' at the bottom of the screen and select the addon file
- Select all objects by pressing <kbd>A</kbd> then deselect emission lights in the Outliner
- In the 'Object Tools' panel on the left-hand side of your screen, scroll down to 'Setup Wire Render'
- Check 'Selected Meshes' then press 'Apply Materials'

Result:
[image]

**Blender Internal: Clay Render addon**

The ['Clay Render'](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Render/Clay_Render) addon adds an option in the Properties>Render menu that allows you to quickly toggle clay on and off.

To use the addon:

- Download the most recent version from [this site](https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-extensions/contrib/py/scripts/addons/render_clay.py)
- In your User Preferences>Addons view, choose 'Install from File' at the bottom of the screen and select the addon file
- In the Properties>Render>Render menu, check the box titles 'Clay Render'

Result:
[image]

*Needless to say, Cycles is better.*

Comment: I think clay render is also available for cycles, it's already included in recent blender version and it's easier to use than the wireframe addon. BTW Gwenn did you answer your own question?

Comment: Answering your own question is just fine on SE.

Answer (score 6):

For Blender Cycles you can try [this method](http://elbrujodelatribu.blogspot.com.es/2013/06/blender-cycles-how-to-make-clay-render.html). You don't need AO or lights. You only have to set a white diffuse material to all objects and use this node setup for your world:

[image]

This is the material for your objects:

[image]

So you can get a clay render like this:

[image]

Go to Properties >> Render Layers Button >> Layer Panel and select that clay material in the Materials list appearing there. That's all.

Comment: I've only skimmed your article, but unless I'm mistaken, you have to manually replace all materials with clay with this method. (Then afterwards undo to get your materials back.)

Comment: No, you don't. There is an option which replaces all materials at once. Firstly, you have to create the clay material in any object. Then go to Properties >> Render Layers Button >> Layer Panel and select that clay material in the Materials list appearing there. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you just select everything, copy it to a new file, make everything the same mesh (Control+J) (and of course excluding the lights and the camera) then make that massive mesh have the clay material? That way youre not doing anything to the original file