# Changing the principal axis in blender

Tags: workflow, customization

I'm quite new to blender and I cant find a way or the option to change the principal axis of a project i.e. from Z axis pointing up I want the Y axis to point up in such a way that the Z axis signifies depth in the scene. I am trying to change this due to the need to see how I will be able to debug the renders that I am doing through code. I would appreciate if anybody would guide me though this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to make Blender a Y-up world?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8999/convert-from-blender-rotations-to-right-handed-y-up-rotations-maya-houdini)  and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/471/is-it-possible-to-make-blender-a-y-up-world