# viewing node outputs

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

If you have a node, it's pretty easy to get it's output in a visual form. With colors, normals, and values between 1 and 0, an Emission shader can be used with a Material-mode viewport...

[image: color]
[image: normal]
[image: value]

...but when any node math results in a value higher or lower than 0, there's no color to represent it.

[image: what is this, anyway?]

Is there any way to view these types of nodes (preferably as a number)?

Comment: related? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23605/how-to-visualize-a-value-resulted-from-math-node