# How can I see the numeric values being sent between material nodes?

Tags: mathematics, shader-nodes

Is there a way I can just hover over, click a button, hold a key, or something, so I can see the actual numbers being sent between nodes? Is there an add-on or something? I'm tired of guessing.

[image: screenshot of shader nodes]

Update - here is a mockup:

[image: mockup]

*** oops, the starting value for the example should've been 242, but I just put that in wrong**

I swear I saw this on some tutorial video somewhere but can't seem to find it again.

Comment: I think it's impossible, because these values are not the same on the whole model. For example if you plug a mask texture into one of the sockets the output value will be different on every pixel of the image. So the result won't be clear.

Comment: this is very tricky if not impossible because unfortunately there is no feature implemented. So you will have to find workarounds for this. Try to check through the comments and answers in this thread https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10673/debugging-material-math-nodes-in-cycles/10675#10675 someone mentioned something about OSL script.

Comment: [Here is a similar question](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/is-it-possible-to-read-the-output-values-of-nodes-from-a-material/7899) at devtalk.blender.org (quote) *"The nodes in a nodegraph are only a visual representation they do not actually do anything, at render time they get compiled into a shader program that’ll either run on the gpu or cpu but you can’t query a nodes outputs from python. It also doesn’t really make a whole lot of sense in most cases, when you query the output of a noise texture in a node graph what are you expecting to see there? or a glossy node?"*

Comment: And here (https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/23605/107598) is a solution to display the result of *Math* nodes.