# How can I see the numeric values being sent beteween material nodes? MOCKUP

Tags: mathematics

Does anyone know of an add-on, property, or something, that will show the values being passed between material nodes?

Is there a way I can just hover over, click a button, hold a key, or something, so I can see the actual numbers being sent between nodes? Is there an add-on or something? I'm tired of guessing.

*** oops, the starting value for the example should've been 242, but I just put that in wrong**

[image]

Comment: You've already asked that here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/268089/how-can-i-see-the-numeric-values-being-sent-beteween-material-nodes and got an answer that it probably can't be done.

Comment: this is very tricky if not impossible because unfortunately there is no feature implemented. So you will have to find workarounds for this. Try to check through the comments and answers in this thread https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10673/debugging-material-math-nodes-in-cycles/10675#10675 someone mentioned something about OSL script.

Comment: The previous question didn't answer it because the previous question didn't give the image example properly. 

I swear I saw this on some tutorial video somewhere but can't seem to find it again but the last one was answered with seeing the Material Output, not the numeric values. So I specified more with these images.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address raised the issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)