# Extracting data from nodes?

Tags: node-editor

Similar to a [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10673/debugging-material-math-nodes-in-cycles) asked a few years ago about debugging math nodes, I was curious if there is anyway to dump the numerical data output from a math node to any external location that would allow one to see the actual numbers?  Say possibly a CSV file, a numpy array, a SQLite or pandas table, or something within the blender UI itself?  If not, what might be the most promising route to implement such a feature?

Comment: why not using the small osl code from the second answer to the linked question?

Comment: So I was able to use that script to write a single value to the system console. When the value being inspected is vector or matrix and is printed for each pixel, the debugging experience in the system console window is slightly painful.  I'll look into what it might take to write an OSL shader that could output values to one of the formats listed above.  That might be just as painful to develop, but would definitely be useful.

Comment: For the math node in the shader system, if the input is not a scalar value, it is practically impossible to view its value. That is because it is not represented in a discrete form and rely on the general scene settings, even discrete data like images are interpolated to be continuous. So the only way to view the data is to discretize it, that is, render the scene and view the values of its pixels.

Comment: @ABG, the problem is that for any call of the shader will result in a different output... you can render with less samples which will print less values. I normally prefer to keep track of the limits for any input.