# View or export data from Nodes (eg Voronoi texture node)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I have the following nodes on Suzanne (see image)

[image]

and I would like to see what data "Voronoi Texture"-node spits out on "Fac" output. I would like to see it in numbers. A vector, a matrix, or something. Directly to a file or in a console.

Is this possible?

I tried with the script from this link:
[Debugging material math nodes in cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10673/debugging-material-math-nodes-in-cycles)

Without any success, rendering just stops at 0 %.

Comment: I think you can use baking to get your voronoi saved to a texture: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90096/how-can-i-convert-a-node-made-material-into-an-image-texture

Comment: When I tried that method, it gave me an error "No active image data", so instead I'll try to solve this by creating a camera pointing at a plane with the material.