# Rendering World Position Pass

Tags: render-passes

I need to render a world position pass in Blender to check if my idea is correct. I found solution that uses an emissive material and geometry node to render position as colors: [How to render world position pass](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7397/how-to-render-world-position-pass)

[image]

When I render the scene presented below:

[image]

I get this result:

[image]

The image seems to look fine, but when I check the values with the image view something's wrong.Each cube is size of 2 and spacing is equal 1. Cubes are translated in x direction and the first-left one is placed in origin.
I assume then that the first-right cube should have values of R component within the range 12-14. Intead of that values are around 2.7.  What do I do wrong?

---EDIT---

I did everything as Martin recommended. Anyway I still have same problem:

[image]

I attach the .blend file where the problem occurs. I will be very grateful if you find the problem:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bMnmEB9-j2OQllZKqfwwWkgx2ZlvTFx3/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Color management?

Comment: Any tips, what I should set in color management? I tried a lot of variants. The most logical one would be Raw mode in my opinion. There is no one named 'linear'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting Display Device to 'None'(because you do not want it to be an image viewd on any display device, but only pure unchanged values) in the scene's color management settings:

[image]

Seems to work:

[image]

Obviously the output needs to be a 32bit full float EXR image in this case as well if you want to save it.