# How to output deep data?

Tags: render-passes

Is there a way to export world position pass, also object position pass (local), and deep pass ?

I have searched in the output tab but haven't found anything.

thanks a lot!

Comment: AFAIK Cycles doesn't support deep compositing data at this time. You might have some luck with third party renders.

Answer (score 1):

Passes are accessible in the view layer tab:

[image: passes cycles]

Though there are not world/object position passes yet, you can make them by hand like explained on [this other topic](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7398/53447). It explains only for the world position, but you can deduce how to do for others.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question was originally asked, Blender began supporting AOVs (arbitrary output variables) which allow you to treat any data you can get in a material as an output pass:

[image]

Here, I'm using an AOV to do a world position pass.

Make a new AOV by clicking the plus button in properties/viewlayer/shader AOV and give it an appropriate name.  Then create an AOV output in your material and set it up appropriately.  My AOV material here is outputting unprocessed world position.  Any AOVs you create will show up as passes in your compositing.

I don't know a way to preview AOVs in Cycles, but they can be previewed in Eevee by adjusting the render pass output on the preview dropdown while in rendered or material preview modes.