# 3D movies for 3D TV

Tags: rendering, animation, blender-internal-render-engine

How can I make a 3D movie that does not have colors on it. A movie like the ones on the blue rays. So that I can what it on my 3D-TV?

Comment: You can render a SBS in MP4 This works fine on my Samsung 3d in full color

Comment: @user20017 SBS?

Answer (score 4):

You could set all materials to one monochromatic color as described here:
[How to quickly do a clay render?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1404/how-to-quickly-do-a-clay-render)

In Blender 2.75 a steresopic mode has been added see the release notes for details:
http://www.blender.org/manual/render/workflows/multiview.html

A still current tutorial which uses external tools you can find here:

Tutorial:
http://3d.simplecarnival.com/stereoscopic-rendering-in-blender-part-1-a-blender-overview/

Git-Project:
https://github.com/simplecarnival/3d-blender-tools/archive/master.zip

Comment: Yes of course. I know that this feature got added. But then you have red and blue or other colors in the image of you set them. But is there a way to render a 3D movie like the ones that are on bluerays?

Comment: @rudolf97 I could be wrong, 3D blu ray uses MVC (Multiview Video Coding) is a relatively new amendment to the H.264/AVC standard. Blender currently supports only H.264 so you could render so you would need some blu ray mastering software.