# How do I work with grayscale?

Tags: color, lut

I would like to work with greyscale like this photo.

[image]

I have a landscape and models. What should I do first?

Comment: This site works best if you only ask one question per post. However, you can post as many questions as you would like. Also, your reference image in your first question in not grey scale, only shades of grey. It is "Monochromatic" shades of one color.

Comment: Before changing all materials check this (clay render): http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1404/how-to-quickly-do-a-clay-render

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most elegant solution is using [color management](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/post_process/cm_and_exposure.html?highlight=management) and a custom matrix to convert the image's color information to a grayscale.

You can easily and non-destructively represent your scene in grayscale without the need of changing materials or affecting the overall quality of the render.

User @troy_s has created a LUT pack and OpenColorIO (OCIO) config that greatly enhances blender's display transform.

Included in the pack there are a couple of matrices that can be used to set grayscale looks.

> - *Greyscale on Desaturation* This is a greyscale preview of the desaturated look helpful for evaluating contrast and other details in some contexts.
> - *Greyscale* This is a greyscale preview without the desaturation look applied.

[image]

LUTs and OCIO configuration can be downloaded at [this Github link](https://github.com/sobotka/bassam-test) along with the instructions on how to install and use.

For other related topics read [this link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/46940/1853)

Comment: Using a colour managed look to achieve the result would indeed be preferable. The reason is that a conversion to an achromatic image relies on colours. In this case, the image in question is not, and rather sepia, but the same concepts apply. By crafting a look, you will be able to leverage the colours of the scene in your creative output, and possibly shift between looks as required based on the context of the scenes.

Comment: Hello folks! I'm trying to locate the greyscale LUT inside the provided Github link (above), but I can't find it anymore. Does anyone knows where I can find it? Thank you!

Comment: The greyscale transform is in both LUT packs at the GitHub link. It is in Looks.

Comment: Thanks Troy! I'm sorry but i have another silly question. If I install it correctly the name of the "Look" inside the GUI will still appears as "Greyscale sRGB/709 primaries" ? Thank you very much for your time! :)