# Creating an accurate sodium halide (Monochromatic ) light source

Tags: node-editor, lighting

I'm trying to create a sodium halide light. The effect of this light is that it only shows a single spectrum (out of the full rainbow of visible light), thus any object that isn't yellow, looks grey or black. I wasn't sure how to go about creating this light source.

Using Cycles . Version 2.79 (haven't had time to invest in 2.8, I know I should. Def will very soon).

Appreciate the help

Comment: Noob here and I havent worked with nodes yet, but did a bit of googling and if you don't have too many textures, it seems that you could add a "RBG to BW" node to your textures? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/converter/rgb_to_bw.html

Comment: Or - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48944/how-do-i-work-with-grayscale

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. I did ended up faking my textures that way, but it would still be interesting to find out if theres a way to create a monochromatic light source

Comment: WHile I was googling, it appeared that it isnt possible sadly