# How to turn off textures in Blender Internal render?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, interface

Actually I know that there is an appropriate option in render tab in *Shading* rollout. But it seems to work only with usual materials, not node-based.

I want to make fast render without shading and textures just for the preview and can't figure how to disable textures in node-based materials.

Some sort of python script which mute all textures would be usefull.

EDIT: Added screenshot of set-up I have
[image: Nodes]

Comment: As in doing a [clay render](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1404/935)?

Answer (score 2):

Go to the *Texture* header and uncheck the desired texture slot checkboxes in *material textures* tab. Then render.
[image]

Comment: In the screenshot I added recently you can see that I don't have such options when nodes are in use. All I can do is mute textures, but it is way too much work for many materials

Comment: @SergeL You will see those options if you select Material node in the Node Editor. This won't make muting textures easier though. You can select all the nodes which are connected to the material node of *Texture* type and mute them. Unchecking *Textures* in Shading rollout will make all the textures become invisible.

Answer (score 2):

So, I found decent python script for this job.
Source: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/13611/29200

First, run this script in *Text editor*:

```
import bpy

for mat in bpy.data.materials:
    mat.use_nodes = False
```

Now all materials become simple and ready to be affected by *Texture* option in *Render settings*

To turn things back you need to change **False** to **True** in the last line and run script another time.