# Blender internal: How to get a plain rendering of an object by ignoring its materials?

Tags: rendering, mesh, materials, objects, blender-internal-render-engine

I wonder is there an easy way to render an object in the scene without its materials to get a rendering of a plain shape? By "without" I mean somehow hiding the materials that are applied to the mesh without removing them. The only option that I thought could help was "Traceable". However, after I unchecked Traceable the materials still show on the object after rendering. The hard way to do this is to remove all of the materials but I wonder if there is an easier solution to this?

In summary, I want to go from this:

[image]

To this, without removing the materials:

[image]

Comment: Traceable only moves material away from raytracing calculations like mirror, raytracing shadows or anything possible with Ray Tracing option in Shading tab, it's not related to rendering material in general. If all you want to do is to render every object with only one material then use Render Layers tab, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1404/1245

Comment: @MrZak I updated my question. I basically want to get the "plain" rendering of an object without adding/removing any materials. But just by somehow deactivating the currently-applied materials to the object. Do you know any solutions for that?

Comment: You can choose a material for the **material override** field in the render layer settings.

Comment: As per answer in the linked question: *"In the Properties area, Render tab, Layer group, there's a setting to override every object's material"*, https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1411/1245. One material used as ovewriting one should be set up first. The rest of materials are not touched in any way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to the redundancy of answers in the comments:

[image]

You don't need to remove the materials for the objects in the scene or alter them in any way. Just select a material you want for the render and use it on the material section for the render layer. All of the other materials assigned for the object will be ignored.

From the [Blender manual:](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/post_process/layers.html)

**Material Override**

> Overrides all material settings to use the Material chosen here.
>
> Examples of where this might be used:
>
> To check lighting by using a plain diffuse material on all objects.
>   Render a wireframe of the scene.
>   Create a custom render pass such as an anti-aliased matte or global coordinates.

**EDIT:**

Newer versions of blender don't use layers, but "collections" so the override function is in the scene>View Layer section.

[image]

Additional info:

[Where is the Layers panel in Blender 2.8?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96463/where-is-the-layers-panel-in-blender-2-8/96465#96465)

[2.8 - Is it possible to assign (override) a material to a whole collection?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/136678/2-8-is-it-possible-to-assign-override-a-material-to-a-whole-collection)