# How can I render my scene with all materials white in Blender 2.8? (Clay Render)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

Is it possible to quickly turn all my materials white so that I can render my scene like the following picture? (rather than manually assigning a white material to all objects and then having to go back and turn everything back to its correct material).

[image]

Comment: I would make a copy of my file and load that instead of reverting to correct materials otherwise after making everything white. And i would make one object white, select all other objects and then the white object last, and use Make Links, Ctrl + L > Materials to make them all white. Should work right away if every object has one material slot.

Comment: The answer given in the old question linked above is quite outdated. If you're using Blender 2.83 or 2.90, the easiest way would be to go to View Layer > Override and set a white material there. Then all objects will be rendered using this material.

Comment: You can always suggest an edit @GordonBrinkmann Something like: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1411/31447 ?

Comment: @Jubei Updated the accepted answer in the dupe. Something else?

Comment: @brockmann thank you! Let's delete it.

Comment: You're welcome. I'd suggest to leave it here, helps future visitors finding that topic @Jubei

Comment: @brockmann I'm still quite new to Blender Stack Exchange. If I knew I could do that I would have gladly tried to gather some reputation ;)