# How do change the shading for an entire scene?

Tags: python, rendering, scripting

I've seen a number of questions dealing with rendering in the 3D Viewport or making particular objects render as wireframe. What I can't find is a way, from Python (or even manually), to set the entire scene to render as wireframe or any of the other shading modes that we can use in the viewport. I want to be able to render an output image in wireframe or solid, instead of the normal rendering mode.

How can I render an image, that I can save to my drive, with everything as wireframe or solid?

Comment: Cycles or Eevee? For cycles, enable 'Material Override', allows to set any material you want, see [How to quickly do a clay render?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1404/how-to-quickly-do-a-clay-render) (potential duplicate). Unfortunately this feature is missing in Eevee yet and hopefully will be implemented soon.

Comment: one quick possibility is using viewport shading and then view -> viewport -> render image

Comment: @Chris: So that renders the viewport image and not the view from a particular camera? (I've noticed when I select a camera in the viewport, it's from the same angle, but shows more than the camera shows.)

Comment: @Tango It depends.  If you're in a camera view (numpad 0), your viewport render will show you a render from the camera-- no viewport zoom, no borders, no passpartout.  If you're not in a camera view, it will show you whatever you're seeing in the viewport, although if rendering to a different aspect than your viewport, not exactly the same.

Comment: @Nathan I know I can find this, but I'm spending so much time researching, I hope you don't mind me asking you a question to save a few minutes. Is there a way, in Python, to set the view to a camera in the 3D Viewport? I'm making a number of renderings from a list of cameras, so I know I'm selecting them one at a time. I take it, after I've selected a camera, I can specify a way to render and save the Viewport image from that camera? And I take it that would look much like a normal camera view, except with my changes?

Comment: @Tango Sorry, I don't know scripting Blender.  Should be possible though.