# How do I make a light show in "solid mode" in the view port?

Tags: 3d-view, lighting

I want a light to affect the view port when your model is gray; the solid circle in view port shading. The light is only visible in "rendered mode". How do I change that?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you just want it to look like solid shading, so is your actual question how to create something that looks similar in material preview or render? Because if so, that's not very clearly explained... Or do you specifically want to view it in _Solid_ mode because the performance while working in the viewport is better with this shading? Well, then I have bad news, the performance is better because it does not take any lights etc. into account, so even if you could make it use lights, the advantage of better performance would be lost.

Answer (score 2):

Solid mode, by definition, does not use lamps. It has simple, fixed lighting, either from a predefinted HDRI or a matcap, in Blender's case. (some other 3D software uses fixed lamps, for example)

If you want lights in the viewport, you should use rendered or material preview mode. That is one of the main distinctions between these modes and solid! The other distinction being materials are used in this mode. If you want rendered mode without materials, you can try switching to a different render pass such as diffuse-direct.

[image: viewport shading menu, with the diffuse direct pass selected]

Alternately, if you're using Cycles you can use a layer override to replace the scene materials, as described here: [How to quickly do a clay render?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1404/how-to-quickly-do-a-clay-render)